# interpolate vector field in vtk from unstructured grid to structured grid

Tags: c++, interpolation, vtk

I want to interpolate a 2 dimensional vector field from an unstructured grid to a structured grid.

I think the interpolation works, but I do not know how to retrieve the interpolated vector field. I need the field for further calculations, thus I do not need the vtk formats and classes after retrieving the field on a structured grid.

So, my question is how do I access the interpolated velocity field?

The header of the input file is

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
Unstructured Grid from OpenGeoSys
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
FIELD TimesAndCycles 2
TIME 1 1 double
1.000000000000e+002
CYLCE 1 1 long
1
POINTS 20301 double
```

The code for reading in the data and interpolating is mainly taken from the [InterpolateMeshOnGrid](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/InterpolateMeshOnGrid) example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vtkUnstructuredGrid.h>
#include <vtkGenericDataObjectReader.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkDelaunay2D.h>
#include <vtkProbeFilter.h>
#include <vtkPointData.h>

int main ()
{
    std::string inputFilename = "data.vtk";

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader> reader =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(inputFilename.c_str());
    reader->Update();

    vtkUnstructuredGrid* ugrid = reader->GetUnstructuredGridOutput();
    int cell_no = ugrid->GetNumberOfCells();

    //create structured grid
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> grid_points = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
    int grid_size0 = 10;
    int grid_size1 = 5;
    double dx0 = .1;
    double dx1 = .1;

    for(int i = 0; i < grid_size0; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < grid_size1; ++j)
        {
            grid_points->InsertNextPoint(i*dx0, j*dx1, 0);
        }
    }

    //triangulate the grid points
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelaunay2D> delaunay = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDelaunay2D>::New();
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    delaunay->SetInput(ugrid);
#else
    delaunay->SetInputData(ugrid);
#endif
    delaunay->Update();

    //create a dataset from the grid points
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> grid_poly_data = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
    grid_poly_data->SetPoints(grid_points);

    //perform the interpolation
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkProbeFilter> probe_filter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkProbeFilter>::New();
    probe_filter->SetSourceConnection(delaunay->GetOutputPort());
#if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
    probe_filter->SetInput(grid_poly_data);
#else
    probe_filter->SetInputData(grid_poly_data);
#endif
    probe_filter->Update();


    vtkPolyData* spdata = probe_filter->GetPolyDataOutput();
    vtkPointData* spoints = spdata->GetPointData();

    std::cout << *probe_filter << std::endl;
    std::cout << *spdata << std::endl;
    std::cout << *spoints << std::endl;


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the output is

```
vtkProbeFilter (0x8a04d0)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 621713
  Reference Count: 2
  Registered Events: (none)
  Executive: 0x8a1280
  ErrorCode: Success
  Information: 0x8a0690
  AbortExecute: Off
  Progress: 1
  Progress Text: (None)
  Source: 0x89e4c0
  SpatialMatch: Off
  ValidPointMaskArrayName: vtkValidPointMask
  ValidPoints: 0x8a0ed0


vtkPolyData (0x89a720)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 621833
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Source: (none)
  Information: 0x899810
  Data Released: False
  Global Release Data: Off
  UpdateTime: 622378
  Release Data: Off
  UpdateExtent: Not Initialized
  Update Number Of Pieces: 1
  Update Piece: 0
  Update Ghost Level: 0
  MaximumNumberOfPieces: -1
  RequestExactExtent: Off
   Field Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 621812
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Arrays: 0
    Number Of Components: 0
    Number Of Tuples: 0
  Number Of Points: 50
  Number Of Cells: 0
  Cell Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 621820
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Arrays: 0
    Number Of Components: 0
    Number Of Tuples: 0
    Copy Tuple Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 )
    Interpolate Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 )
    Pass Through Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Scalars: (none)
    Vectors: (none)
    Normals: (none)
    TCoords: (none)
    Tensors: (none)
    GlobalIds: (none)
    PedigreeIds: (none)
    EdgeFlag: (none)
  Point Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 621833
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Arrays: 1
    Array 0 name = vtkValidPointMask
    Number Of Components: 1
    Number Of Tuples: 50
    Copy Tuple Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 )
    Interpolate Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 )
    Pass Through Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Scalars: (none)
    Vectors: (none)
    Normals: (none)
    TCoords: (none)
    Tensors: (none)
    GlobalIds: (none)
    PedigreeIds: (none)
    EdgeFlag: (none)
  Bounds: 
    Xmin,Xmax: (0, 0.9)
    Ymin,Ymax: (0, 0.4)
    Zmin,Zmax: (0, 0)
  Compute Time: 622391
  Number Of Points: 50
  Point Coordinates: 0x8a1990
  Locator: 0
  Number Of Vertices: 0
  Number Of Lines: 0
  Number Of Polygons: 0
  Number Of Triangle Strips: 0
  Number Of Pieces: 1
  Piece: 0
  Ghost Level: 0


vtkPointData (0x89aab0)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 621833
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Number Of Arrays: 1
  Array 0 name = vtkValidPointMask
  Number Of Components: 1
  Number Of Tuples: 50
  Copy Tuple Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 )
  Interpolate Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 )
  Pass Through Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 )
  Scalars: (none)
  Vectors: (none)
  Normals: (none)
  TCoords: (none)
  Tensors: (none)
  GlobalIds: (none)
  PedigreeIds: (none)
  EdgeFlag: (none)
```

Thanks alot in advance!